# Automatic Opening of Msg Dialog Box when coping a file

Tags: excel, dialog, powerquery, file-copying

When I copy excel data from query (excel file) to another excel file's datasheet, a message dialog box is automatically poping up. Could you please help to solve this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtYX6.png)

Comment: Please show the code that you have so far, so other ca see what you've tried and where you're stuck. Here's some info about [ask] and also see how to create a [mcve].  Also be sure to check out the [tour].

Comment: Actually, I didn't write any code. I simply copying a data from one excel sheet to another, then a dialog box pop up as shown in attached file :)

Comment: this happens to EVERY file you copy from.. or only certain file with external data link (in the copied data) ?

Comment: this is for the first time for me, usually I copy data from one excel to another file. But for the first time, this is from a Microsoft Excel Web Query File. Is it because of it?